# Sequel Sinatra Post Database params

Tags: ruby, sqlite, sinatra, sequel

I am trying to build just a very simple form for registering attendees for my wedding. This is somewhat a draft because I don't know if I'll be using Sinatra or Rails. I am going to be setting up scheduled emails to notify guests and myself of the wedding specifics.

So anyway here is the code I can't get anything to persist to the database using the     insert    syntax. Some code has been omitted. This is just pertaining to the POST issue.

```
    require "sinatra"
    require "sequel"
    require "sqlite3"


    DB = Sequel.connect('sqlite://pauley_wedding.db')

    DB.create_table! :attendees do 
     primary_key :id 
     string :fname
     string :lname
     string :phone
     string :email
    end

    @attendees = DB[:attendees]
```

here is the routes/views:

```
    get '/' do 
     erb :index, :layout => :layout
    end

    get '/about' do 
     erb :about, :layout => :layout
    end


    get '/rsvp' do 
      erb :rsvp, :layout => :layout
    end

    post '/rsvp' do
      @attendees.insert(:fname => params[:fname], :lname =>                                       params[:lname], :phone => 
    params[:phone], :email => params[:email]) 
redirect '/confirm_rsvp'
   end

    get '/confirm_rsvp' do 
        erb :confirmation, :layout => :layout
    end

    get '/admin' do 
        erb :admin, :layout => :layout
       @attendees
    end

    @@rsvp 
    <style>
    h1 {
        color: tan;
    }

    .lead {
        color: tan;
    }
    </style>
    <h1><p class="lead">Sign up!</p></h1>
    <form action="/rsvp" method="POST">
    <p class="lead">First Name:</p><br /><input type="text" name="fname"><br /><br />
    <p class="lead">Last Name:</p><br /><input type="text" name="lname"><br />   <br />
    <p class="lead">Phone Number:</p><br /><input type="text" name="phone"><br      /><br />
    <p class="lead">Email Address:</p><br /><input type="text" name="email">
    <hr />
    <button class="btn btn-primary" input type="submit">Sign Up!</button>

    </form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't appear as though `@attendees` in the first code block is the same as `@attendees` in the second code block.  In the first code block, `@attendees` is set in what appears to be top-level code. In the second code block, `@attendees` is used inside a route, which is going to be an instance of the Sinatra class you are using.  You could try to use `ATTENDEES` (a constant) instead of an instance variable.  You can also add a database logger `require 'logger'; DB.loggers << Logger.new($stdout)` to see what SQL Sequel is sending the database.